# C# Most elegant way to convert string array to dictionary with different keys

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have a collection of string arrays (result of splitting CSV to rows and then delimiting)
`{31001, 2014-01-01, 24:00:00},{31001, 2014-01-02, 24:00:00},{31001, 2014-01-03, 24:00:00} ...`
Now I need to convert it to list of dictionaries, where each dictionary element will have custom key depending on arrays element index. So I want to achieve something like this:

```
{
 {"Index":"31001", "Date":"2014-01-01", "Time":"24:00:00"},
 {"Index":"31001", "Date":"2014-01-02", "Time":"24:00:00"},
 {"Index":"31001", "Date":"2014-01-03", "Time":"24:00:00"},
 ...
}
```

I can't use models for this

Comment: As the data you have seems to be JSON, have you considered using JSON.Net https://www.newtonsoft.com/json ?

Comment: Sorry. What are the keys, and what are the values?

Comment: I need to hardcode keys. So first array element should have "Index" key, second - "Date", third - "Time"

Comment: What you was you want to achieve does not look like dictionaries, it looks like JSON.

Comment: So whats the values?

Comment: Then you should probably create a class with members `Index`, `Date`, and `Time`. A dicitonary holds *one* key and *one* value, not multiple values. Then simply deserialize the data using some Json-serializer likle NewtonSoft.

Comment: The result should be the list of dictionaries

Comment: I didn´t mean a dictionary contains only a single entry at all, just one value per key. So you won´t need a list of dictionaries. Apart from this as you have duplicate keys you should use a `LookUp`  instead, or as already mentioned a class that holds the information for one entry. Then you can simply create a list of that class holding the entries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will have duplicate keys you could use something like

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,Tuple<string,string>>
```

where the key is the **Index** and the rest of the data belongs in the Tuple (Date,Time,..etc).
If you will have more data you couls simply use a `List<KeyValuePair<string,List<string>>>`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an anonymous object.
this way would result in objList having all the rows with the properties Index,Date and Time. whilst not using named classes.

(please note I'm still learning if I don't name things right)

---

```
List<Object> objList = new List<object>();

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var fields = line.Split(',');
    objList.Add(new {
        Index = fields[0],
        Date = fields[1],
        Time=fields[2]
     });
 }
```

---